# How to safely restart my mariaDB galera cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera

**I have three galera node with slave replication node it's smoothly running .But when i shutdown or reboot my machine then again want to restart my mariadb galera cluster but it is not start.please help**

Comment: This question is about administering a database cluster, not about programming, therefore it is off topic here on SO. The DBA sister site of SO offers help in database admin type of questions.

Comment: What is the error message you are getting ?